# squid - access denied for wordpress site locally

Tags: wordpress, apache, access-denied, squid

I have Apache locally and use it for web development. The sites that i build locally need to have the same url with the online (some issues with the database). So i installed squid 3.3 . Then I made squid to read a different hosts file from the system's. So I connect firefox with squid so as to have firefox use the new hosts file and let chrome use the normal hosts file.

Also I have created a virtual host on apache like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /Path_To_Root/example
ServerName www.example.com
```

Inside that folder I have installed a wordpress multisite.

Also inside the new hosts file that squid uses (with the directive hosts_file /etc/hosts_squid) I have set 127.0.0.1 to be www.example.com

BUT when I try to access the site www.example.com/foo (which is locally) from firefox (that uses squid) it says access denied.
In the access log file of squid it says

> 127.0.0.1 TCP_DENIED/403 3806 GET http://www.example.com/foo/ - HIER_NONE/- text/html

Does it has to do with the redirection that wordpress makes?
Do I have some wrong configuration in the htaccess file?

All the other sites that are outside the example folder they are functioning properly.

Answer (score 0):

Requests for resources which doesn't exist (HTTP Error 404) or a client doesn't have
permission to access the requested resource (HTTP Error 403) are common and requests
to such resources make up a significant percentage of the total requests. These responses
are cacheable by Squid. However, sometimes web servers don't send the Expires HTTP
headers in responses, which prevents Squid from caching these responses. To solve this
problem, Squid provides the directive negative_ttl that forces such responses to be
cached for the time specified. The syntax of negative_ttl is as follows:

```
negative_ttl TIME_UNITS
```